# Disable JMS consuming bean in unit-test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jms, javabeans

I've build a Spring application that receives JMS messages (`@JmsListener`).
During development I'd like to send some messages to the JMS-queue the listener listens to, so I wrote a unit-test that sends some messages (`JmsTemplate`). In this unit-test I use `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` in order to load the application context (beans for datasources etc).

However, when the unit-test starts, it also loads the jms listener bean which directly starts consuming my new messages.

I would like to disable this jms listener bean in this test scenario so that messages are just added to the queue. Then later, I can start the main application and watch them being consumed.

How should I approach this?

I guess I could also have asked how I could disable a bean in general.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You could use **profiles** to solve this problem.

To your listener, add the `@Profile` annotation:

```
@Profile("!test-without-jmslistener")
public class JmsListenerBean {
    ...
}
```

This tells Spring that it should only create an instance of this bean if the profile "test-without-jmslistener" is **not** active (the exclamation mark negates the condition).

On your unit test class, you add the following annotation:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test-without-jmslistener)
public class MyTest {
    ...
}
```

Now the Spring test runner will activate this profile before running your tests, and Spring won't load your bean.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using profiles you can also achieve this with a property:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "jms.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class JmsListenerBean {
    ...
}
```

The matchIfMissing attribute tells Spring to set this property to true by default.
In your test class you can now disable the JmsListenerBean:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "jms.enabled=false")
public class MyTest {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem: add `@ComponentScan()` to the test class to skip the loading of the specified beans.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.pechen.demo", excludeFilters=@Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes=JmsListener.class))
public class MyTest(){

}
```

Any more please refer to [spring component scan include and exclude filters](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-component-scan-include-and-exclude-filter-example-using-javaconfig-and-xml-with-annotation-assignable-aspect-and-regex-filter-types).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by this code:-

```
private void stopJMSListener() {
    if (customRegistry == null) {
        customRegistry = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
    }
    customRegistry.stop();
}

private void startJMSListener() {
    if (customRegistry == null) {
        customRegistry = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
    }
    customRegistry.start();
}
```